# work with .hpp files

Tags: c++

The codes in my main program are given below; here I read a file called test.dat and data of this file put in to my structure so for that I used a class called MyData (my_data.hpp).

```
int main()
{
  // cout<<"this my program"<<endl; // when this delete, this codes are not working
   bool ok=true;
   MyData  my_data("test.dat", ok);   
   if(ok==false){
      cout<<"Error, unable to read file1.";
      return 0;
   }
   ACalculation a_calculation(&my_data);
```

For the calculation part, I used another class, AClaculation (a_calculation.hpp). Here I used pointers to speedup my program.

```
ACalculation (MyData  * my_data){
MYData::iterator i;
for (i= my_data ->begin(); i!= my_data ->end(); i++){

if(i->A() > max){
          max = i->A();
          }

}

cout<<”my max value is:”<<max;
```

My program does not show any errors but when I run it, it does not show the result of my max value. But when I added a “cout” code at the beginning of the main program then it shows the result. It means, when I delete this line:

```
cout<<""this my program";
```

the program does not show correct output. But when I add it again, it workq. I can't understand where the error of my program is?.

Please help me to find out my mistakes here.. thanks

Comment: I don't see max declared anywhere, so this isn't the code you have a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to flush the console printing an endl

Comment: @aki: cout<<”my max value is:”<<max<<endl

Comment: yes it is a mistake but my problem is when i change any thing inside my classes its not take for the out put but if I add any new line into my main programm before call my class ACalaculation, then it takes counts my updats inside class. i think that problem is there but i can not solve since it complied successfully.

Comment: my problem is that my program is not updating properly. for example, i did some editing inside my classes and complied all classes and also main program, although no complier errors, my changes are not include in my output it is a older one. but if i change something in main programm before call my classes and then it is working. please help me to find error here.

Comment: @aki: so weird. never happened things like this to me

Comment: any way to help me, may be i can send you my whole codes if i have your contact mail. pls. help me thanks

Comment: @aki: sorry, i'm not c++ guy, can't help